# Checking text as you write it

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a function  (in Python 3) which will allow someone to revise a set text.

Set texts (in this situation) are pieces of text (I am doing the *Iliad*, for example) which you need to learn for an exam. In this function I am focusing on a user trying to learn the translation of the text off by heart.

In order to do this, I want to write the translation in a text file, then the user can test themselves by writing it up, and the program will check whether each word is correct by checking it against the known, correct translation.

I know I could simply use `input()` for this, but it is inadequate as the user would have to type the entire text, or small parts, at a time for this to work, and I want to correct as they type in order for them to remember their mistakes more easily.

I have not written any code yet as how I write the rest of the program will depend on how I code this part.

Comment: Use something like Tkinter. The question is too broad and is likely to be closed as such. But note that IDLE (written using Tkinter) does real-time syntax highlighting as you type, which is sort of what you want.

Comment: ah ok, thanks. Is there any way I can improve the question or is it just too broad overall?

Comment: You are going to need to use some GUI toolkit (if not Tkinter then something else -- see this for options: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming ). Pick one that has a text box control. Learn how to use it. Eventually you will have questions -- but the question is unlikely to be GUI toolkit independent.